# why doesn't this simple require.js setup work?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to learn how to use `require.js` to load my scripts, but something is wrong with my setup/understanding. I can't see what is wrong. It is something simple with the setup that I'm missing.

When I load this `index.html` page in chrome, none of the script `require.js` action is working.

***index.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>My Sample Project</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="h1">sample project header</h1>
   <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***main.js

```
(function() {
  requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from baseUrl
    baseUrl: '',
    // paths config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    // never includes a ".js" extension 
    paths: {
      'small-blue-mod': './a-script'
    }
  });

  // Start the main app logic.
  requirejs(['small-blue-mod'], function (sbm) {
    alert(sbm.color);
  });
})();
```

***small-blue-mod.js

```
define({
   color: "blue",
   size: "small" 
});
```

*File System looks like...

```
index.html
main.js
require.js
FOLDER called "a-script"
```

`a-script` folder contains `small-blue-mod.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `small-blue-mod` refers to the `a-script` folder, either require it like `small-blue-mod/small-blue-mod` or recommended change your path to this:

```
paths: {
  'small-blue-mod': './a-script/small-blue-mod'
}
```